# React: Count number of components + re-render all of them with updated total

Tags: reactjs

I have `<Box>` components created sequentially from a parent component. At the end each `Box` needs to show `X of Y`, where X is the current index and Y the total.

e.g.

```
<Box .. />
<Box .. />
<Box .. />
RENDERED RESULTS:
1 of 3
2 of 3
3 of 3
```

There are two parts to this problem: (1) get the current running index, (2) re-render all `Box` components with the total after they're all rendered.

I'm not sure where to start, even for Problem (1). Suppose in the Parent I have

```
const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

return (
    <Box index={count} />
    <Box index={count} />      
);
```

and in the `Box` component

```
export default function Box(props) {

  (props.index)++;

  return (
    <div>
        Running Index: {props.index}
    </div>
)
```

}

But that gives me the error **TypeError: "index" is read-only**

Comment: Take a look at [Lists and Keys](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html), it may help. Props are immutable, and the `count` state is declared `const`, so it can't be reassigned a value anyway.

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Does the Parent not know how many boxes there are when rendering? One ugly solution to this is to pass a function that setState from parent to child as a prop that runs once via useEffect.

Comment: Yes, the likely solution is to make the Parent aware of how many children it'll be creating in advance (maybe from an object array). I'll use Drew Reese's option #1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

Props are immutable, and the count state is declared const, so it can't be reassigned a value anyway.

## Solution

The parent should/would typically know what it's rendering. Typically one would render an array of data, via `Array.prototype.map` where you have both the length of the array being rendered ***and*** the current index in the mapping callback.

```
const Box = ({ index, total }) => (
  <div>
    Running Index: {index} of {total}
  </div>
);
```

Example:

```
const [boxData] = useState(initialState);

...

{boxData.map((data, index) => (
  <Box index={index + 1} total={boxData.length} />
));
```

If you are looking for something a bit more "automagic" then you can create a wrapper component to automatically inject the `index` and `total` props. It first clones the component and then injects the extra props.

```
import { cloneElement, Children } from "react";

const BoxWrapper = ({ children }) =>
  Children.map(children, (child, index) =>
    cloneElement(child, {
      index: index + 1,
      total: Children.count(children)
    })
  );
```

Now you can render children `Box` components:

```
<BoxWrapper>
  <Box />
  <Box />
  <Box />
</BoxWrapper>
```

[image]

### Demo

[image: Edit react-count-number-of-components-re-render-all-of-them-with-updated-total]

Comment: Great, thanks. I'll go with Option #1 where I can pre-determine the number of components.